# DataContext in Window_Loaded

Tags: wpf, events, datacontext, loaded

I'm very new to WPF. I'm currently doing a code to detect joints coordinate using the Kinect SDK and displaying on a simple textbox in WPF. The code to detect joints are in a private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) method. To display the coordinates, I used DataContext. Without further ado, let's just see the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="Prototype.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="480" Width="640">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="coordinateText" Width="150" Height="20" Margin="441,409,27,12" Text="{Binding Path=xInfo}"/>

</Grid>
```

And this is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Research.Kinect.Nui;
using Coding4Fun.Kinect.Wpf;

namespace Prototype
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //this.DataContext = new Coordinate { xInfo = "5" };
        }

        Runtime nui = new Runtime();

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DataContext = new Coordinate { xInfo = "5" };
            nui.Initialize(RuntimeOptions.UseSkeletalTracking); //code for detecting joints

            //some code for detecting joints

        }

        public class Coordinate
        {
             public string xInfo { get; set; }
             public string yInfo { get; set; }
             public string zInfo { get; set; }
        }
    }
 }
```

The thing is the information will not be loaded in the textbox if  this.DataContext = new Coordinate { xInfo = "5" }; is not placed in the MainWindow. I have to put it in the Window_Loaded method. Any solutions?

Comment: why cant you have the Coordinate class as a property of this main window class and just change the xInfo in window_loaded event?

Comment: thx Coder323 for the reply. But would it make a difference? If yes, why? can u also give a small example? I'm very sorry I'm still new to WPF :(

Comment: wait, I would recommend you to use MVVM where you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

Comment: so you mean i have to set the DataContext in the OnPropertyChanged method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Coder323 said When window is loaded you need tell WPF TextBox that the Value of the variable `xInfo` is changed so you should use INotifyPropertyChanged in your Model Class

then where ever you change theValue of your Object it will pick up the changed Value... also 
Just Set the `DataContext=myCordinate` in the Window Constructor then, make my cordinate a variable in the window class.

```
    public class Coordinate : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
         private string xInfo;
         public string XInfo {
                                get{retun value}; 
                                set{
                                     xInfo=Value;
                                     FirePropertyChanged("XInfo")
                                   } 
                             }


         public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
         protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
         {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
         }

   }
```

Do this for other properties and now you can set the value of myCordinate.XInfo="what ever you like" in any event it will notify to your view that the respective property has changed..

I am putting my complete solution here

## My Coordinate class

```
public class Coordinates : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string xInfo;
    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string XInfo
    {
        get { return xInfo; }
        set
        {
            xInfo = value;
            InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("XInfo"));
        }
    }

    public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

## My Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=XInfo}" Height="30" Widht="100"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

## My Xaml.cs

```
namespace TestApp
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Coordinates myCoordinates;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        myCoordinates=new Coordinates();
        this.DataContext = myCoordinates;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myCoordinates.XInfo = "Acbd";
    }
}
```

}

And yes this test Project i made... is working

This might Help :)

Comment: i can't copy my code here and i can't answer my own question..thx for the effort though guys..i think it has something to do with the Window_Loaded method. I also can't write anything on the output console if I put Console.WriteLine () in the Window_Loaded method..

Comment: @user1055010 I have added a complete solution

Comment: thanks a lot..it finally worked!!!!!! apparently my mistake is i didn't write Loaded="Window_Loaded"...... -__-"..man how i wish everybody is like you :)..well the algorithm for coordinate tracking is still not functioning properly, but at least this problem is done..thanks a lot :)

Comment: if it worked Marked the answer as right so it might help others